# Vue3 Props Wrapped in Multiple Proxies

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, dynamic, components

So I'm using a Vue3 dynamic component that cycles through .vue files based on an array of objects, as such:

**EDIT**: this is how component is assigned

```
const pages = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: null
    props: {
        ...
    }
  },
  ...
]

const component = computed(() => {
  if(pages.value) return {...pages.value}
})


<keep-alive>
  <component :is="component.name" :key="component.id" :props="component.props" @updateName="nameUpdate" />
</keep-alive>
```

One of the pages takes a name as an input, and returns it to the `<component>` in `nameUpdate`:

```
const nameUpdate = (newName) => {
  component.value.forEach(step => {
    if(step.name === null) step.name = toRaw(newName)
  }
}
```

This works as expected, it assigns the value `newName` to the other objects that contain `name`, and when console.log'd as props (console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props)), it displays as:

```
props: Proxy(Object)
    *expanded* Object
       *expanded* name: 'test'
```

and when attempting to access, such as `props.name`, it returns `undefined`.

Is there a proper way to emit a name back to a an array of objects for the Vue3 dynamic component pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. In your code `component` is not reactive while it's treated as a ref in other place, `component.value`

Comment: Sorry, edited the display for `component`, its actually a computed value.

Comment: I see. It's a bad practice to mutate a prop in a child, so yes, it should be emitted to a parent. A parent should have enough info to mutate it, i.e emit both `id` and `name` to change a name of array element. It's unclear what's the problem with "multiple proxies" and console.log. Generally you don't need to pay attention to them

Comment: Right, so the "proxies" portion was mainly a signifier as to something not working correctly due to how it was displayed, so I guess the main question is: How should I go about emitting the name change into various different objects within `component`? As in, if there are 5 objects that contain `name: null`, and I need them all to be updated when the first `name` is changed and submitted?

Comment: This doesn't indicate there's something wrong, also this is inconsistent with `SON.parse(JSON.stringify` part because there would be no proxy in a console this way. Again the problem needs a reproduction. It's all in the details that seem to be omitted. `pages` is an array but you use it as an object and also a ref, `{...pages.value}`. It's unclear why `component` is a computed. A computed generally shouldn't be mutated because the changes will be overwritten on its update. If `pages` is supposed to be mutated and reactive, just make it reactive and mutate it directly